# Check the tag,branch of a checked file CVS

Tags: tags, branch, cvs

I'm wondering is there a command line option to find the actual revision number and which tag/branch a currently checked out file(s) belongs to in CVS?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cvs status` will do that for you. eg.

```
nova:cvstest $ cvs status README 
===================================================================
File: README            Status: Up-to-date

   Working revision:    1.1 2014-07-02 22:03:46 +0100
   Repository revision: 1.1 /Users/burhan/cvsrepo/cvstest/README,v
   Commit Identifier:   UqYgDdPSIHB0zQGx
   Sticky Tag:      (none)
   Sticky Date:     (none)
   Sticky Options:  (none)
```

The `Sticky Tag` line will show you the tag/branch.

Check the documentation for more information on what this command can do.